# Deselect selected rows from ag grid angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-ng2

Is there any grid api to deselect ag-grid selected rows programatically?
I'm trying to perform some operation on the selected row, basically an async operation , after which I need to deselect this row from the grid .

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Used grip api deselectAll function . It worked !

```
this.gridOptions.api.deselectAll();
```

Comment: this works fine but due to this table is continuously refreshing

Comment: Can we deselect any specific row in aggrid?

Comment: It is better to assign the API object into its own object (and run this function from it), upon "gridReady" event, but basically this code works fine for its purpose. Thanks

Comment: My solution was similar, but I did not need gridOptions. Since I already had: ````onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent) {this.gridApi = params.api}```` I just could do this: ````this.gridApi.deselectAll()````

Answer (score 9):

I believe it is weird but setting `rowDeselection` to `true` didn't work for me. What I wanted was simple: **Being able to deselect a row when it was selected already**. So I checked the [Row Selection](https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/) section of AG Grid's documentation and I find this:

> rowMultiSelectWithClick: ... Clicking a selected row in this mode will deselect the row.

Huh! Yeah that sounds like what I need! But I don't want multiple selection...! I want single selection ONLY. So I thought *maybe* setting `rowSelection` to `single` will fix it and the selection will be **single and deselectable**. And... yes it works! The reason I was in doubt initially when doing this is using "row**Multi**SelectWithClick" together with "**single** rowSelection" sounds contradictory, but it works anyways and this is the thing that matters really! :)
So e.g., if you're using it in React (quite similar in Angular or Vanilla JavaScript), just add:

```html
<AgGridReact
    rowSelection="single"
    rowMultiSelectWithClick={true}
    //...
>
```

Answer (score 8):

For anyone that finds this in the future:

Allow manual row deselection by setting `gridOptions.rowDeselection = true` as Victor said.

Programatically deselect all rows using `gridOptions.api.deselectAll()` as OP discovered.

To programatically deselect a single row, use `rowNode.setSelected(false)`.
`rowNode.setSelected(isSelected, clearSelection)` can be used to select rows as well, and will deselect all rows other than the subject rowNode if `clearSelection` is `true`.

Comment: What is rowNode, where do you get it?

Comment: A `rowNode` is the datatype returned by the functions that get rows.
Examples of these functions called from the gridApi: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/grid-api/#reference-rowNodes
Read more about row nodes here: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-grid/row-object/

Answer (score 3):

You could try the deselectAll() method in the GridApi. Though, it doesn't appear that AgGrid has an option to deselect specific rows.

Comment: Yes, Though I was having single select ag grid instance , So this worked.
But If you want to deslect some specific rows you can use api.forEachNodeAfterFilter( function(node) {
  // select the node
  node.setSelected(false);
});

Comment: Nice~ I have faved your question. because I use AgGrid myself and might stumble upon this issue myself eventually :)

Answer (score 3):

set gridOptions.rowDeselection to true with rowSelection as multiple will deselect a selected by click when holding control key.

Answer (score 2):

To deselect a specific row/node use api.getSelectedNodes() instead of getSelectedRows(). Then for each node use node.data for the row info you need and then node.setSelected(false) to deselect when done.

```
let selected = gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();
_.each(selected, function(node) {
    let row = node.data;
    //stuff
    node.setSelected(false);
});
```