# Ag-grid vuejs checkbox deselction on click of row or label is not working

Tags: vue.js, ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I am working on `ag-grid` with vue.js, I am not able to deselect an checkbox with click of the row, able to select with click of row, deselection also working on click of ctrl + click, I want that to happen on with direct click not in combination of `ctrl + click`. How to do that ?

Plunker link for the same - https://plnkr.co/edit/itq2xUlaDQm1dwKX

```
<ag-grid-vue
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    @grid-ready="onGridReady"
    :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
    :suppressRowClickSelection="false"
    // :suppressRowDeselection="false"
    :rowSelection="rowSelection"
    :rowData="rowData">
</ag-grid-vue>
```

Comment: Duplicate - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199849/deselect-selected-rows-from-ag-grid-angular

Comment: I just checked the plunker that you have and it is working fine with single click.

Comment: I figured out the answer thanks, updated in the same plunkr link