# How to call Ag-Grid onSelectionChanged event clicking on same row multiple times?

Tags: reactjs, gridview, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I am using Ag-grid library for grid view in React app. Following is my Ag-Grid component:

```
const handleChanged = (gridOptions) => {
    const selectedNodes = gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes()
    //TODO
}
            <AgGridReact
                data-testid="details-data"
                columnDefs={DetailsColDef}
                rowData={formatDetailsData(
                    data?.Response,
                    false
                )}
                rowSelection="single"
                reactNext={true}
                defaultColDef={defaultColDef}
                onSelectionChanged={handleSelected}
                suppressPaginationPanel={true}
                domLayout="autoHeight"
                suppressMaxRenderedRowRestriction={true}
                rowBuffer={5}
                suppressColumnVirtualisation={false}
                debounceVerticalScrollbar={true}
                alwaysShowVerticalScroll={true}
            ></AgGridReact>
```

**Current Scenario:** handleChanged is getting called when we click on Grid row.
**Requirement:** Need to call handleChanged event every time on multiple click at same time. Currently event is getting called first time only. If we click again on same row, it need's to be called.

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71105532/13405106) add `rowMultiSelectWithClick={true}`

Comment: @Usama Thank you for your answer. It's working for deselecting the row. But I want data of row on deselecting it.

Answer (score 2):

You can call `gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes()` inside [`onCellClicked`](https://www.ag-grid.com/archive/26.2.0/react-data-grid/grid-events/). Every time the row/cell is clicked you will get the data

```
const onCellClicked = (e) => {
    const selectedRows = gridOptions.api.getSelectedNodes();
    console.log(selectedRows)
}

 <AgGridReact
   onCellClicked={onCellClicked}
   ....
  >
 </AgGridReact>
```

Check [working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/w8iCw61vUrRgaKYm?open=index.jsx&preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to use onSelectionChanged out of its scope, if you need to see if a cell is clicked (any number of times, you can use the onCellClicked Event). there are multitudes of events that can be used if that doesn't suit your needs.
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-events/#reference-selection

Otherwise if you are going to use this event only one handy way would be to change the selected row at the end of your processing and making this process async. this would be be problematic if the user clicks the row you have chosen to set it to so not the optimal solution i would say.
https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/#node-selection-api