# How to Unselect/ deselect all rows in a React AGGrid grid or reload the grid easily?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a React AGGrid grid with some rows and i can select a row/rows by clicking on a checkbox in a row. Anyway I need to deselect all checkbox/ checkboxes selected in rows when clicking on a button. How do I do this? Please help.

I tried this by using a setState and it didnt work. Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deselect selected rows from ag grid angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52199849/deselect-selected-rows-from-ag-grid-angular)

Answer (score 0):

Well its pretty straightforward. You can define couple of methods such as these:

```
selectAllRows() {
  this.gridApi. selectAll();
}

deselectAllRows() {
  this.gridApi. selectAll();
}
```

and bind them to the buttons.

You can refer other options here: [Ag Grid React: Selection Events](https://ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/row-selection/)